# Wait for a String to return value

Tags: android, string, android-asynctask

I'm trying to use HttpManager to retrieve a String from a url

```
public String request(Context context, String url){
        page_requested = "empty";
        HttpQuery query = new HttpQuery(context, mHttpClient);
        query.execute(url);
        return page_requested;
    }
```

and use it in MainActivity

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, HttpManager.getInstance().request(MainActivity.this, "http://myurl"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

But `public String request` doesn't wait for query to be executed and returns "empty" but if I wait 10sec to display the toast, it returns the correct value.

What's the best way to display the expected value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use AsyncTask to display your text. I think this will be an efficient way.. you can show your progressbar while loading the operation.

```
public class DisplayString extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{  
@Override
protected void onPreExecute()
{  
    super.onPreExecute();
    dialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
    dialog.setCancelable(false);
    dialog.show();

} 
@Override 
protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    // Things to be done while execution of long running operation is in progress. For example updating ProgessDialog
 }

@Override 
protected void onPostExecute(Void result)

{ 
      //Post Execute
       dialog.cancel();
     //Display your string here
}
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

  // Your operation..Dont Edit Any Views here

    return null;
}
```

}

Hope it helps